# Spring Security+JSF ROLE-driven rendering of page components(link etc.) best practice

Tags: jsf, hyperlink, spring-security, authorization

Usign JSF+Spring Security.

**Solution 1 - UI oriented:**
`JSF` page displays panel with users if authenticated person has `ROLE_ADMIN` authority only.

```
<p:panel rendered="#{facesContext.externalContext.isUserInRole('ROLE_ADMIN')}">
...
```

**Solution 2 - backend oriented** (annotate appropriate DAO method):

```
@Transactional
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
public List<User> getUsers() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class)
            .list();
}
```

**Resume:**
Looks like JSF `rendered` attribute is not flexible solution and DAO annotated methods are not user-friendly,because of redirecting to `403`.

What is the gracefull solution,that allows me NOT to display panel or link,that are not corresponded to specific authorities?

Comment: Why is the JSF rendered attribute "not flexible"? That seems to be the right solution to you, although the particular EL expression can be more simplified.

Comment: I don't know exactly - it's my own feeling.I mean case,when set of roles changed,that you should change `.xhtml` also

Comment: BalusC ,how this EL can be simplified?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't want to show the enduser panels or any kind of functionality which the enduser isn't allowed to see/use anyway. That would only result in general confusion and frustration. So role checking in the `rendered` attribute is the way to go.

The expression can only be more simplified in this form:

```
<p:panel rendered="#{request.isUserInRole('ROLE_ADMIN')}">
```

The [`ExternalContext#isUserInRole()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#isUserInRole%28java.lang.String%29) delegates to [`HttpServletRequest#isUserInRole()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#isUserInRole%28java.lang.String%29), but the `HttpServletRequest` is by itself also present in EL scope as `#{request}`.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security, depending on how it is configured will return 403 or redirect in the event that a user is not authorized to access a specific resource.

Solution 1 is the appropriate way to do what you are trying to achieve but you are essentially creating a dependency between FacesContext and your view which I think is bad practice.  A better solution would be to encapsulate this authorization logic within a managed bean property.  The benefit of doing this is that your view is no longer dependent on your authorization implementation, and your managed bean now appropriately contains that dependency.

Comment: as I understand, `rendered` should be used anyway?but it will hide the declaration concering user role,e.g.: rendered='"#{securedProxy.rolesEnum}' Am I correct?And `SecuredProxy` is the bean,which khows about currently logged in user.

Comment: @sergionni Yes this is correct.  BalusC's answer is more clear than mine.